# What is this copper thing in my soldering kit?

Tags: soldering

[image]

[image]

I found this copper thing in my soldering kit, but as its in Chinese I don’t know what it is.

What is it? It doesn’t look like that thing for removing solder because the wire is very thin, unlike the other thing which looks like a wick of copper. This looks just like plain copper wire. What is it, and what is it used for?

Comment: Fixing mistakes?

Comment: @DKNguyen I don’t understand what you mean.

Comment: You use it for fixing stuff? Like lifted traces, wrong traces, etc.

Comment: @DKNguyen I don’t understand what you mean. Can you elaborate or provide a link explaining what this copper wire is used for with an example.

Comment: Almost looks like wire wrap, for making your own transformers. It can also be used for fine repairs like soldering to pins on LQFP chips.

Comment: @RonBeyer it came with my soldering kit. It looks like copper wire. No idea why it’s included. Need to ask someone who can read Chinese!

Comment: it is not a "copper thing", it is copper wire ... use it anywhere you would use copper wire

Comment: maybe you purchased a hobby soldering iron kit that is meant for making jewellry

Comment: @jsotola it said it was for electronics. I bought two kits. One came with the desoldering braid. The other one had this copper spool (image above). Both has solder suckers, and alternate tips as well as tweezers with “esd “ printed on them

Comment: i am downvoting your question, because it is asking what copper wire is used for

Comment: @jsotola to be fair, not everyone speaks Chinese, and it’s unclear why this would be included in a soldering kit. 

Comment: @jsotola to be fair, copper wire is by definition a copper thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like general purpose lacquer-insulated (漆) copper wire. You should be able to solder through the coating without stripping it (it says no need for scraping 不用刮), but I'm not sure if it's sturdy enough (insulation-wise) for use in coils. You can try bending it around and look at it under a microscope or magnifier.

0.1mm is equivalent to AWG 38, so pretty fine. It might be nice for making dead bug circuits, a bit on the light side for DIPs (AWG 30 is better for that) but okay for fine-pitch SMT parts.

Pretty handy, really, sometimes enameled wire is very expensive in small lots.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Any idea why it’s included in the soldering kit?

Comment: Sort of a little gift, I imagine.

Comment: What do you use it for ?

Comment: It's insulated wire you can solder to. Use it to make electrical connections mainly.

Comment: I see! Very interesting. Thanks for your answer. Also, I looked at your profile, and though unrelated - was wondering if I could ask your opinion. I know close to nothing about electronics (except for what I learned until Grade12 many years ago.) Can I seriously learn electronics to be a competent EE by studying Art of Electronics and working on hobby projects ? Also what is your opinion on 3rd edition vs 2nd ?

Comment: You could be a designer, but without the math background it's quite hard to be a competent EE in many fields. Possible to pick up the math, but not easy. And licensing is probably next to impossible.  AoE 3rd edition and X chapters is much expanded and very useful in practical terms.

Comment: I don’t know what math background is required. But I studied computer science, calculus etc in college. I don’t plan on looking for a job as an EE but was hoping to become competent enough to understand what to design hobby projects that are safe to use.

Comment: Should be no problem, especially with all the special purpose chips, and programming for hobby projects is easily self-taught.

Comment: Ah ok! Thanks very much!